# Притяжательные местоимения Ваш/ваш (ед. число)

Tags: прописная-строчная, местоимения

В последнее время я часто сталкиваюсь с необходимостью использовать сочетания типа "ваша компания", "ваши специалисты", "ваша кафедра" и т. п.

Мне помнится, что было правило написания притяжательных местоимений:
в случае, когда предмет/объект не принадлежит персонально лицу, к которому мы обращаемся, местоимение пишется с маленькой буквы.
Например, **Ваша компания** — в случае, когда компания принадлежит адресату; и **ваша компания**, когда адресат в ней просто работает. Или я в чём-то ошибаюсь?

Буду признательна за комментарии.

Comment: [И все-таки: вы или Вы?](http://gramma.ru/RUS/?id=8.24) Надеюсь, статья ответит на все ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 2):

> (например, "Ваша компания" - в случае, когда компания принадлежит адресату и "ваша компания", когда адресат в ней просто работает).

Вообще подобные вещи не регулируются правилами русского языка. Это правила этикетные, даже канцелярско-бюрократические, а они не подлежат столь строгой кодификации.

В собственно своде правописания есть правило, что "Вы, Ваш" и т.д. - вежливое обращение к одному лицу, а "вы, ваш" - к нескольким. И это при тем, что там есть изрядное число оговорок, они не слишком интересны в теме вопроса. Но и все.

А вот в отношении того, как надо трактовать слова "Ваша/ваша компания", - тут вопрос весьма неоднозначный. Вот вам пример. Если мне в письме надо спросить у Имярекова, например, когда был ремонт в его комнате и установлена ли там система пожаротушения, неужели я должен думать, сколько еще человек в той комнате сидит, и кто у неё хозяин? А если сотрудник, которому Вы пишете, является совладельцем пакета акций, то что, это меняет написание обращения к нему?

Это я к тому, что все вопросы такого плана регулируются деловым этикетом, никак не орфорграфическими правилами. С точки зрения языка корректно считать что "компания Растакоева", даже если этот Растакоев там только дворником работает. И наоборот, Не будет ничего плохого иметь в виду коллектив, обращаясь к руководителю компании. Т.е. в обоих случаях все зависит от сложившейся практики.

По большому счету, я не вижу ничего плохого в том, чтобы Вы следовали изложенному Вами правилу. Оно понятно и в чем-то естественно. Только не ищите это правило в учебниках по русскому языку. Его там точно нет.

Вы проще поступите. Представьте на минутку, что адресат - ваш хороший знакомый, пишете вы ему это письмо не для официальной регистрации. Вы как напишете? Твоя или ваша компания? Если "твоя", то пишите Вы, речь идет об одном лице. Если ваша - так и будет ваша. Получится примерно то же самое, что и у вас, но все-таки будут и различия.

Answer (score 0):

Вы совершенно правы, Светлана.

То же самое для предметов. Ваш с маленькой буквы подразумевает то, что к этому коллективу, предмету причастны или имеют отношение определённая группа людей, в том числе и тот, о ком Вы говорите.

Например, *Ваш стол (Василь Иваныча, к которому Вы обращаетесь),* но *ваш (например, обеденный) стол* применительно к членам семьи, в доме которых он стоит.